# Running ZFS commands as a non-root user

Tags: zfs

I just set up a zfs pool on my ubuntu 16.04 system.   I created some datasets in the pool and used 'zfs allow' to delegate permission to snapshot, rollback, etc to a non-root user.  Then I tried to use those datasets as that user.  It fails with the message 'Permission denied the ZFS utilities must be run as root'.  Turns out, I can't even do a 'zfs list' command without being root.  Having to be root to execute *any* zfs command defeats the purpose of the zfs delegation model.  Am I missing something here?  I'm using the ZFS support built into ubuntu, not the FUSE version.

Comment: I'm guessing that the program needs to be installed suid root, and it is not.  Try using chmod to set the suid bit.

Comment: I should have thought of that.  However, when I set the suid bit, the zfs command lets me do everything, including modifying datasets not delegated to me.  That's a bug, but at least I can operate on my own datasets now without having to sudo.